# How do I get my embed tag to display videos instead of downloading them?

Tags: html, css, web, video, embed

My embed tag keeps downloading the video instead of displaying it.

I have tried changing the file type of the tag, but it just downloads it in a different format. I want the tag to display the video. Here's my code below.

```html
<embed type="video/mp4" src="videos/ymcaHome.mp4" width="400" height="300">
```

Comment: Use the [`<video/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by specifying the video url or the path as the src attribute value. Like this:

```html
<embed src="your_video_file_url.mp4" type="video/mp4" with="640" height="360">
```

Comment: Doesn't op already do exactly this?